# What is the actual danger of power cables inside walls?

Tags: electrical, wiring, walls

I am clear that the NEC codes say not to run power cables (e.g. to a TV) inside the wall. And I also know that romex cable is allowed and perfectly safe inside a wall.

Codes aside, what is the actual difference/danger with a power cord inside the wall (vs it being safe/allowed inside a surface mounted conduit/cable concealer)?

I have a situation where I want to hide a power cord behind a soundbar, and there’s no room to install a recessed power plug that would not be visible.

Is the issue just that power cables “may” not be as well insulated? I *assume* the wire is thick enough to avoid dangerous heat dissipation for the power requirements since the cable came with the product.

Comment: Most electrical wires(in conduit)/cables are run in walls.  Are you talking about extension cables?  Surface mounts are usually used when a wall is finished and people don't want to make a mess, depends on local also.

Comment: I’m talking about the “kettle” or two prong cable power that plugs into a soundbar or a tv. If it’s safe I will put that cable in the wall. 

I’m not talking about extension cable, but the “primary” power cable for a electrical device.

Comment: Think a better question is if your insurance company will allow it.  Insurance likes to get your money, they like it even more when they can get away from paying a claim.  A notarize written okay from insurance would be good to have.

Comment: If a power cable is generating significant heat , it is much too small for the load . You can not insulate for heating of an electric power cable.

Comment: Does the speaker *actually* require 120V?  Or is there a way to bring low voltage to it?  @Crip659 the fire insurance is hardly cheating you *if the illegal+unsafe crud **caused** the accident*.

Comment: I would think the place to start is to identify the cord type from the marking on cord, go to a chart like NEC 400.6 and see the conditions the cord is approved for to see what's missing as it's weaknesses.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Many speakers have built-in amplifiers, and are powered by mains voltage. If the actual loudspeaker in your home movie theater sub-woofer has peak current transients of 20A or more into low impedance (e.g. 2 ohms) which is nothing unusual, why run separate audio cables that will handle that over a long distance when mains power cables already exist? (Of course if you really want to buy audio signal cables that cost $1,000 *per foot*, there are people who sell  them!)

Comment: Yes, the soundbar has an internal power supply and does not have a low voltage alternative. It’s the klipsch 1200 cinema if that helps anyone.

Comment: Is using a piece of duct out of the question? You can get them in all kind of sizes, all kind of colours. I hide most of my cables with ducts, big ones for when I need multiple cables and small ones for single-cable paths.

Comment: If you’re already planning to run a wire through the wall, how about installing a wall socket where you need it, i.e. in the vicinity of the sound bar? Use installation cable that is approved for this purpose, of a gauge suitable for at least the tripping current of your circuit breaker, and tuck the cord behind the sound bar. If the sound bar is large enough to obscure the wall socket, that should achieve your aim, and is safe even if someone later decides to use that socket for a wall heater.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's whats safe, and then there's what has been tested, tested, and tested again to the point it has building codes written about it to be safe.  Is there any real danger running an extension cord through the wall?  No, 99% of the time there's no issue and will never cause a problem.  But then again, a lot of building codes deal with that 1% so avoidable accidents don't happen.

The main issue is actually what you brought up - insulation and heat dissipation.  Extension cords or even device power cords are not rated to any certain specification, and because of that, you can't "know" that it's safe, and you can't publish guidelines about what type of cords are safe because they are so generic.

You might run a cord through the wall to plug in a TV, but then you move out and someone else decides that would be a good place for a wall mounted heater.  So, code says "you can't run extension cords through the wall".  Of course that is exaggerated...  The other issue is that if there is a short and the cord gets hot - how will it burn and is that likely to ignite nearby materials?  Romex has been tested for all of that.

So for a low power device like a TV and soundbar, there is very little risk and you should be fine.  They even make passthrough kits that come with two wall plates and a tube to run the cables through.

In wall power kit: [https://www.amazon.com/-Wall-Power-Cord-Cable-Kit/dp/B00L9K5D5W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L9K5D5W)

Comment: I would be a bit wary of the particular kit noted. There's no indication I can see that says that it meets UL (or other NRTL) requirements. _If_ there were to be a fire in the OPs house and this were discovered there, it _could_ give the insurance company grounds to deny a claim for installing uncertified equipment. As noted in the answer, "there's what's safe and there's what been tested _and certified_ safe" `emphasis added`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. A follow up question: would it be even safer to modify a romex cable with the soundbar plug and run that “romex with plug cable” through the wall instead of the original power cable?

Comment: @FreeMan Good point, but this same kit is sold in store at Home Depot, so I assumed it was UL listed - almost all of their products are because of the reasons you list.  Link was mostly for the pictures.

Comment: @catchdave that's a whole new question, please feel free to add it. Asking new _different_ questions in the comments is forbidden. I'm sure you'll get a good answer to it, as well.

Comment: If it's the same brand kit, then yes, it's probably UL listed. If it's a _similar_ kit, this one may not be. Just a warning for the OP to take into consideration.

Comment: @catchdave Any cable modifications would require some wire splicing, and that adds room for trouble.  The "safer in the wall" aspect would be outweighed by all the other things you would have to do to modify it.  Also, we like to wait a little while before accepting an answer to see if a better answer comes in.

Comment: And then "stuff" happens; A friend put a screw into a wall and penetrated 1/2" steel emt , surprise !

Comment: At the least, splicing would need to be inside a junction box.  I don't see how you can enter the wall without a junction box.  Is there no way to power this thing on low voltage???

Comment: The cable idea I had would be to solder the plug directly onto romex cable… therefore the cable in the wall would have “to code” insulation, and the solder and plug would be outside the wall. I was not thinking of splicing with twist/screw splicing.

Answer (score 27):

### It'll be fine *if everything else is fine*

The #1 issue with cordage inside walls is thermal - cordage is permitted smaller wires *because* it's in the open air in a habitable room, where a human will notice wire problems... not packed in the wall where air cannot circulate and where it may be subject to 150F heat from solar gain.

But the sound bar draws, what... maybe 40 watts?  Less than an amp on a probably #18 power cord. *What could possibly go wrong?*

**We don't install electrical power systems based on everything going *right*.  We wouldn't need GFCIs, grounding, or even circuit breakers, would we?**

But if the speaker has a problem we want it to trip the circuit breaker.  Breakers protect two ways: Instant magnetic trip (at 10x breaker rating, 150A or 200A)... or inverse-time thermal trip, the more the overload the shorter the time.

The inverse-time curve is designed to approximate the overheating of *appropriately sized, appropriately rated* in-wall wiring in the walls.  Those wires have thermal inertia and it takes time for them to overheat.  The idea is that the breaker will tolerate mild overloads for minutes (toaster + coffee maker) or significant overloads for seconds (large motor startup; power supply inrush) because the wires won't overheat *that fast*.

We throw a monkey-wrench in that design when we embed in the wall *cordage*, which has not the insulation thermal rating of other in-wall wire, nor the physical size required - #14 for 15A breaker, and #12 for 20A breaker.

### PSA: Beware *target fixation* on bringing 120V to hard places

I can't tell you how many questions we get where someone is trying  to bring serious, real, human-killing 120VAC to the most improbable of locations.  And we quiz them further, and it turns out they're trying to power a *security camera*. That doesn't even need 120V, it needs 5V.  *But the only way their mind's eye can see to power it, is to bring up 120V and use the usual wall-wart*. (outdoors in the rain no less). Do you see the blind-side there? They're not even considering simply extending the low-voltage wall-wart cable, a safe and legal operation which Code treats lightly because of the low voltage.

Comment: Why does the code think 5V short circuits are unable to start fires?

Comment: @user253751 Because the statistical likelihood of things going wrong enough for a 5V DC circuit served by an approved adapter to start a fire is exceedingly low? A significant majority of low voltage applications in that range are also low current (almost always less than 5A, usually less than 2.5A), so the total power involved is pretty low (yes, you _can_ start a fire with less than 1W of power, but it’s not easy unless you’re dealing with highly flammable materials). There’s almost always more risk of the adapter itself starting a fire than the wiring or load on the 5V side of it.

Comment: Re the PSA - POE is a fantastic way to get power to places like cameras.  One wire, which you need for data anyway.

Comment: A couple of comments:
1. FWIW, my soundbar is rated at 135W which is still only ~1.1amps at 120volts.
2. I would prefer not to send 120volts if I could, unfortunately, the power supply is internal and there is no non-120v power option.

Comment: The other problem with 5V is that you can't send *much* of it very far without either needing an enormous cable *or* having the cable eat up half of the power... there are other solutions, of course.

Comment: @catchdave It's fairly unlikely that those "135 W" refer to any kind of real power. Unless said soundbar is either absolutely ginormous or has active cooling (noisy fans!) to get rid of 135 W of heat (that's two incandescent light bulbs, ever noticed how hot those get?), that value is the so-called "music" or "P.M.P.O." power, which has nothing to do with physics and everything to do with marketing (it's a made-up figure).

Comment: Yep. [This "150 Watt" soundbar](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sharp-HT-SB140-MT-Mountable-Bluetooth/dp/B079Z4HS7S/), for example, only draws 30 watts. So much for the laws of thermodynamics!

Comment: No, this is 135 actual watts. The “max power / pmpo” is 1200 watts for this sound bar (hence the name “cinema 1200”).

Comment: @catchdave Are you sure it's 135 W just for the soundbar? The 1200 W is a sum over the soundbar, a subwoofer and two satellites. I can't seem to find detailed specs anywhere, but it could easily be say 70 W sub + 2x15 W satellites + 35 W soundbar.

Answer (score 8):

It's primarily about the insulation - IIRC, mostly about the flame-spread characterization of the insulation - thus, even non-power cables are different for "in-wall" and "not in-wall" applications, because if the characteristics of the outer insulation layer.

Comment: This is true of Ethernet cable. You get your "regular" stuff, or you pay a premium for "plenum" cable. The wire and insulation _inside_ the jacket are identical, but the plenum cable is rated to be run inside a wall. I'm sure it's 100% the same with power-rated cabling, too.

Comment: Plenum cables are rated for "plenums" that is, spaces that facilitate air circulation.  Plenum rated cables are not required inside walls.

Comment: i've never heard of ethernet cable that's ok for in-wall but not plenum, so it's a distinction w/o a difference.

Comment: @dandavis If it doesn't explicitly say it's plenum, it's not plenum rated. You can use Plenum cable anywhere non-plenum can be used, however.

Comment: **Riser** is the non-**Plenum** in-wall rating for Cat5e/Cat6 etc. "Usually gray," *.vs.* "usually blue" (but both can be had in any color if you want to pay extra, so you have to actually read the printing on the cable to be sure.)